# How did Darken Rahl become Richard's Father?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

In Debt of Bones novella, Richard's mother is still a child when the boundaries are built. 
Then how did Darken Rahl become Richard's father?

Comment: Didn't Darken Rahl attack Richard in the first book where the boundaries were still up anyway?

Comment: @nine9 No. The boundaries fall within a few weeks from start of story in Wizards First Rule. Richard is captured by Denna much later.

Comment: You see, when a man and a woman love each other very much...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shown on the [timeline for SoT](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline) (As a warning if you haven't read all the books the timeline contains many spoilers!!)

- 0 BCB

  D'Haran Midlands War comes to an end.
  First Wizard Zeddicus Zu'l Zorander raises the boundaries between the lands of the New World ending the war.
  Death of Panis Rahl.
- 15 ACB

  Darken Rahl rapes Zorander's daughter, impregnating her.
  First Wizard Zorander exiles himself to Westland, taking his pregnant daughter with him.
  Richard Cypher is born late "15 ACB" or "16 ACB" to the First Wizard's daughter, and George Cypher raises him as his own.

So Zedd erected the boundaries first then crossed after his daughter was raped.  The boundaries don't prevent powerful wizards from crossing, since Zedd erected the boundaries he had an understanding of them.

Note on [boundaries](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Boundaries)

> The only way to cross a boundary was with the assistance of powerful
>   wizards, or to go through a pass in the boundary. The only known pass
>   is one between Westland and the Midlands, called King's Port. It was
>   generally known only to boundary wardens, but was also used by George
>   Cypher, Richard Rahl and Kahlan Amnell.

Comment: "The boundaries don't prevent powerful wizards from crossing" I imagined this was the main reason why a boundary is being erected

Comment: @SuryaPratap yes I know but I didn't write the books, I added an additional note on them :)

Comment: Actually going through the boundary by a wizard wasn't straight forward and they could easily die from the things within.

Comment: I liked the books, but honestly I like what the TV show did more, making them brothers instead. That simplified a lot of things.

Comment: @Omegacron Keep reading the books and you will realize why they can't be brothers in the books.  The issue is with the link that makes them Lord Rahl.